# CSS Issue - Why 4 * 25% is NOT 100%

Tags: html, css

I've been looking around all over the posts and see lots of discussions similar to mine but no exact answer unfortunately. So let me describe the case and ask you why that happens, what is the reason for this weird behavior.

So, I have a very simple HTML page with a parent container and a list of unordered items ul which is set to width: 100% and consists of 4 li items each of which is set to width: 25%; I definitely do reset every possible layout property to zero, but in spite of that in the end of the day the four list elements are with total width that exceeds 100%. What is the reason which makes the browser render 4*25% != 100% in spite of all the resets I do???

Here's the code and thank you in advance for your answers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en">  
<head>  
<meta charset="utf-8" />  
<title>Test</title>  
</head>  
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;">  
<div id="wrapper">  
  <header style="width: 960px;">  
      <nav>  
      <ul style="width: 100%; padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important; background-color: yellow; ">  
         <li style="width: 25%; border: 0 !important; background-color: #f00; display: inline-block; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important;"><a href="#" id="active">Dashboard</a></li>  
         <li style="width: 25%; border: 0 !important; background-color: #0f0; display: inline-block; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important;"><a href="#">Mobiel</a></li>  
         <li style="width: 25%; border: 0 !important; background-color: #00f; display: inline-block; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important;"><a href="#">3</a></li>   
         <li style="width: 25%; border: 0 !important; background-color: #f0f; display: inline-block; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important;"><a href="#">4</a></li>  
      </ul>  
    </nav>   
  </header>  
</div>      

</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

I think the problem is that you set the `display: inline-block` property, so the `<li>` elements are treated as inline elements and the newline characters between each line introduce whitespace which the browser renders as spaces between the "words".

Change your HTML to put the closing `>` on the following line, i.e.

```
<ul style="width: 100%; padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important; background-color: yellow; ">  
    <li style="width: 25%; border: 0 !important; background-color: #f00; display: inline-block; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important;"><a href="#" id="active">Dashboard</a></li  
    ><li style="width: 25%; border: 0 !important; background-color: #0f0; display: inline-block; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important;"><a href="#">Mobiel</a></li 
    ><li style="width: 25%; border: 0 !important; background-color: #00f; display: inline-block; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important;"><a href="#">3</a></li   
    ><li style="width: 25%; border: 0 !important; background-color: #f0f; display: inline-block; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important;"><a href="#">4</a></li>  
</ul>
```

This fixes the issue on Firefox for me.

Comment: A good solution to the problem is to remove the `</li>` completely.

Comment: Ahaaaaaa, I see, so when using inline-block every single new line character is being accepted as white space, that DOES make sence.
Thank you for your response, MUCH appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

place `float:left` in the **LI** will fix the problem

```
li { float:left; }​
```

This should take care of the white-spaces that are created.

**Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/G3Jxv/

Answer (score 1):

You could also set the font-size and/or line-height to 0 on the <ul> and then reset it on the child <li> elements since there is a space automatically added between inline elements.

But the other solutions work too

Answer (score 0):

You can try floating the elements, using `float:left` on the `li` elements. Or, should avoid white-space in between `li` declarations:

```
<li><a>Test</a>
</li><li>
  ...
</li><li>
```

Take a look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdiaz/JnmEx/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove whitespace between li elements, using CSS

```
ul {word-spacing: -1em;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    letter-spacing: -1px;}

li {display: inline-block;
    font: normal 13px/1.3 "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    vertical-align: top;}
```

Answer (score 0):

It just because,there are 'enter's between 'li'.

Try remove all 'enter's between 'li's, like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li>
</ul>
```

**EXAMPLE:**

> https://codepen.io/baofengyv/pen/XRgJoW